# how transform vector to another vector space in python/pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a vector with fixed column size, for example from 0 to 9, initially are all 0s.[0,..0]

And, I want to transform vectors like [1,2,3] as [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0,...0]

Is there any way to do it other than iterate through every number?

I created a data frame already and trying to insert each vector in the data frame. I'm trying to achieve something like:

1. [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0 ...]
2. [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0 ...]

   ......

Comment: I may be misreading this, but it is not exactly clear to me what is the nature of the transformation you are trying to make.  Can you be more specific about inputs and outputs?

Answer (score 0):

Use `numpy`.

```
zeros = np.zeros(9)
zeros[[1,2,3]] = 1
```